# Can we solve the following ODE via reduction of order? $y''+y'''\sin(y)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with one problem in particular.

$y'' + y'''\sin(y) = 0$ is the equation.

I am told to let $y' = z$ and do reduction of order to give:

$z'+z''\sin(z)= 0$

But I am absolutely stuck. I don't know what a possible solution would be to do reduction of order. I thought about $A\cos(y) = z$ as a solution.

Any advice?

Comment: Is the differential equation $y''+y'''\sin(y)=0$ or $y''+y'''\sin(x)=0$?

Comment: y''+y'''sin(y) = 0

Comment: You've been told to use the substitution $z=y'$? I don't see how that will help you deal with the sine term.

Comment: If you had $y''+y'''\sin(y')=0$  then the substitution $z=y'$ would yield $z' + z'' \sin(z)=0$. But you have $y'' + y'''\sin(y)=0$ which is totally different.

Comment: yes, I have been told to use y' = z and use reduction of order to eventually get this into a separable equation. It's quite confusing.

Comment: Are you sure the original equation isn't $y''+y'''\sin(y')=0$? If it were, then $z=y'$ would transform this into $z'+z''\sin(z)=0$. Rearranging terms we can say $z''=-\frac{z'}{\sin(z)}$. Now using the fact that $z''=\frac{dz'}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=z'\frac{dz'}{dz}$ we can say $\frac{dz'}{dz}=-\csc(z)$ which is seprapable.

Comment: absolutely positive this is y′′+y′′′sin(y)=

Comment: If you use the fact that $y'''=\frac{dy''}{dy'}\frac{dy'}{dx}=y''\frac{dy''}{dy'}$ you can rewrite your original equation as $\frac{dy''}{dy'}=-\csc(y)$ but I wouldn't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

With reference to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0503.pdf,

Let $u=\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=2\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$2\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{du}{dy}$

$2\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt u\dfrac{d^2u}{dy^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{du}{dy}\pm\sqrt u\dfrac{d^2u}{dy^2}\sin y=0$